# Both logging and print statements inside django channels consumer are not working

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-channels

I'm trying to integrate celery with django channels but channels consumer is not working as it supposed. Logging or prints inside consumer functions are not displaying message in terminal.

The following celery task is called from signals.py

*tasks.py*

```
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer


@app.task
def send_request_notification():
    text = 'You have new cleaning request'
    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()

    async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
        'companies_received_request',  # group name 
        {
            'type': 'send_notification',
            'text': text
        }
    )

    print("SENT ---")  # can see result of this print
```

*consumers.py*

```
class NotificationConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        logger.info("Connected to websocket")

        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            'companies_received_request', self.channel_name
        )
        await self.accept()


    async def disconnect(self):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            'companies_received_request', self.channel_name
        )
        logger.info("Disconnected from websocket")


    async def send_notification(self, event):
        logger.info("Here in sending notification")

        text_message = event['text']
        await self.send(text_message)

        print("EVENT.TEXT")
        print(text_message)
```

*settings.py*

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [('127.0.0.1', 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

I am supposed to get the output of prints and logging of consumer functions in terminal but I'm getting nothing when I call `channel_layer.group_send` method from `celery` task. (It seems that `celery` couldn't make a connection to `consumer`)

Comment: can't you see the log `logger.info("Connected to websocket")` at all?

Comment: Yes, at all. Plus, cannot see prints too. But, asgi server is running. What might be wrong here?

Comment: did you configured the `redis` correctly? is `redis` server up and running?

Comment: Yes, redis server is working. Because when I connect to socket from [link](https://websocketking.com/) I can see log in connect() method. Regarding send_notification method it's working when I first receive from user and use it inside that receive method. When I directly use send_notification method from celery task (like above), nothing is working neither connect nor send_notification methods. I think when i use send_notification from celery it couldn't make a connection. Any ideas what is the problem?

Comment: this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64774400/celery-task-can-not-call-channels-consumer-via-channel-layer-send) may be useful